# HOT(Heap On Top) Queues

Tags: c++

Could anyone point me to an example implementation of a HOT Queue or give some pointers on how to approach implementing one?

Comment: Well, maybe you could explain the concept of a HOT Queue so that we can propose some design to implement it.

Comment: Implementation of this is going to be very use specific.  More information is required.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.2448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a page](http://www.lonesock.net/misc.html) I found that provides at least a clue toward what data structures you might use to implement this.  Scroll down to the section called "Making A* Scalable."  It's unfortunate that the academic papers on the subject mention having written C++ code but don't provide any.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the paper describing HOT queues. It's very abstract, that's why i wanted
to see a coded example (I'm still trying to fin my way around it).
http://www.star-lab.com/goldberg/pub/neci-tr-97-104.ps

The "cheapest", sort to speak variant of this is a two-level heap queue (maybe this sounds more familiar). What i wanted to do is to improve the running time of the Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

> What i wanted to do is to improve the
>   running time of the Dijkstra's
>   shortest path algorithm.

Have you considered using the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)?
If you are using your own implementation of the algorithm you might already get better results using [the one the BGL provides](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html).

However It might be nontrivial to modify your code so it works with the BGL.

Of course speed-up could also be gained by not using Dijkstra at all but another algorithm.